# Combinatorics intuition

Tags: combinatorics

I am working through a problem and I would like to have some advices.

I am trying to solve counting problems without using shortcuts as binomial coefficients and such ( mainly to build intuition and be able to solve more complicated problems without getting too confused on when to use this formula or not).

I am trying to solve the following problem(I reduced a larger problem to the following toy example )
Suppose we have 3 letters, A,B,C.
We Want to count the number of string containing 2 letters where A can be repeated. So basically (AA,AB,AC,BC) = 4.

I am trying to find a systematic way of solving these problems. So I start like this :

Consider our alphabet of A1, A2, B, C. The number of ordered string containing 2 characters is 4*3=12

Now the number of string containing 2 characters where order doesn’t matter is 4*3/2!=6.

From there I do not know how to modify the formula to eliminate the redundant As. Since all multiplication or division are valid only if it applies to all strings.

Any ideas ?

Here is the larger problem:

how many ordered full houses (eg KKKQQ) are there in a deck of 52 cards ( holding 5 cards ). My solution :

We have 52 choices for the first card, let’s say we picked a king, we have then 3 choice to pick the next king, and 2 choices for the last. Then we have 48 choice for the card constituting the pair and it follows 3 choice for the second card of the paire.

So we have 52*3*2*48*3. This will count all full houses of the form (KKKQQ) where K could be any card and Q any card different than K.

Now we need to divide by 3!*2! To account for the permutations of KKK and QQ. Then to get all the possible ordering we need to multiply by 5! To have a full permutation.

By doing the last step we also allowed unnecessary permutations (the Ks for example) so we need to divide again by 3!*2! But according to the results I see online I do not get it right...

How to intuitively and systematically get the answer right ?

Comment: You can opt to break into cases based on whether or not there is one $A$.  This occurs four times in your example if the $A$'s were considered distinct.  Now, in this subcase we can divide by two to account for the $A$'s being considered identical, so by correcting the current count of $6$ by subtracting the $2$ mentioned earlier gives us the expected answer of $4$.  In general, if you can't apply division arguments to the total collection of arrangements, you may still be able to apply them on a case-by-case basis.  This can become tedious though as the problems get more complex.

Comment: Can you share the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you! I added an edit to my post!

Comment: As for the number of ordered full houses... pick the rank of the triple, pick the rank of the pair, pick which suits are present for the triple, pick which suits are present for the pair.  This gives $13\cdot 12\cdot \binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$.  If by "ordered" you mean the cards must appear in ascending order (*with cards of same rank appearing in the order $\clubsuit<\diamondsuit<\heartsuit<\spadesuit$*) then this ends the calculation.  If instead by "ordered" you mean that the order in which the five cards appear in hand is considered relevant, multiply by an additional $5!$.

Comment: Remember that the $K$'s and $Q$'s in your full house example *are distinct*!  You have a king of clubs which is *different* than a king of spades or a king of hearts etc...

Comment: If the second meaning of ordered I give above, then you may alternatively first pick the rank for the triple and the rank for the pair.  Then pick which pattern the cards appear in (aaabb, aabab, abaab, ...).  Then from left to right, in those slots designated for the triple, choose which it actually was, do the same for the pair.  This gives $13\cdot 12\cdot \binom{5}{3}\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 3$, the same answer as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

First just take A,B,C and count the number of ways,  $\binom 32$ = 3

Now, just count if we take 2 A's: only one way AA.

So, total number of ways = 3 + 1 = 4

If this doesn't help you, please share your bigger problem.

**For the bigger problem**
You need 3 cards of same kind and two of another kind. Choose your first card of one kind. 
$\binom {13}1$  and then choose rest 3 cards in $\binom43$ .
Now choose second type card in $\binom{13-1}{1}$ and 2 cards from those 4 cards $\binom{4}{2}$.

So, $\binom{13}1 \binom 43 \binom{12}1 \binom42$.

Comment: The asker requested a method not using binomials

Comment: @QthePlatypus I have not used bionomials I guess, I have just selected cards, which i have represented like $\binom nx$ instead of nCx

Comment: nCx is the binomial theorem my reading was that the asker wanted an answer without using that tool.